# Is it acceptable to improve a very old question to match your also very old answer?

Tags: discussion

**Background**

I answered a certain [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18459122/2431281) long ago. It was too localized back then but I was a newb and I answered it. Now it is gathering some views because of its title.

My answer back then was also too localized. I answered in a way that the OP could just copy and paste my answer for it to work. Now 2 years has passed when I noticed that it is still gathering views and giving me reputation, so I decided to improve my answer. I added an explanation of the gist of my previous answer but I did not delete the original answer entirely.

**Assumption**

It has been 2 years since the OP was last seen here in SO. I assume that the question and answer has already served its purpose for *him*.

**What I want to do**

Since it is gathering views, I expect it to gather more views in the future.

- I want to edit the question to make it more readable, and more consistent to its title.
- I want to remove the source code provided in the question.
- I want to change the title from *Play sound on button click android* to *How to play a sound on button click in Android*.
- I also want to delete my original answer entirely as it's of no use right now. IMO the explanation is enough.
- If deleting my original answer is too much, then I will just remove the parts(parts that address the OP's coding mistakes) that make it *too localized*.

Doing this, the question will be reduced to something like:

> How to play a sound on button click in Android?
>
> How do you get a button to play a sound from raw on click? I created a button with id `button1` and I do not know how to proceed.

Now if I do this, I am afraid that my edit will be rejected as *deviates too much from the original intent*. I also am not sure if it is correct to do this things. There is that [Explainer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4368/explainer) badge so I assume that this is somewhat encouraged. I then read this [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/?cb=1) and this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-%E2%86%92refiner-%E2%86%92-illuminator) but I'm afraid that my edit is still too big that it warrants some feedback from the community.

**Question**

Is it correct to proceed with what I want to do or should I just forget about it and get on with my life?

Comment: There is a significant risk that the votes will stop coming when you make such a drastic edit.  It is not always obvious why a particular question gets the Google juice.  But pretty safe to assume that the less text you leave in the question, the less likely it will match a keyword that another programmer searches.

Comment: @HansPassant I reread the question and I think you're right. Some words (e.g. youtube, tutorial, stackoverflow, work) in the question could have lead Google to point at it [as the first result](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+play+sound+on+button+click+in+android). I'll just improve its readability (e.g. spelling, some grammar). Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with improving your old answers, in fact it's encouraged.

You also don't need to keep a copy of the original text at the bottom of the answer  - that will be available in the edit history.

However you should not "improve" the question to make it fit your answer - as you guessed it deviates from what the OP intended. If you figure that there is room to write a *better* question that your answer can be applied to then you can always write the new question and self answer it.

Comment: First and foremost, the question is not really of good quality. If I were to see that question today, I would probably flag to close/downvote it or something. Second, I think it already served the purpose of the OP so I'm kind of convinced that editing it would be a good idea (for future visitors). But if the community thinks that it's okay as it is, I will leave it as is. I'll wait for other people's opinions.

Comment: @Keale Ask a new question (or find an existing good question) and copy the generic parts of your answer over there.  Then edit your current answer to show the old, localized fix and explain it's an instance of the general case, with a link.  Hopefully search will go to the good question; if not, you have a link in the old question to redirect users.

Comment: @Keale Also, your new answer is great.  Please find a good home for it, one way or another.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Thanks! I did a quick search [and](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19464782/2431281) [found](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2753943/2431281) [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26538421/2431281) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3041763/2431281). All of them have accepted and upvoted answers similar to mine (the solution is really really common so I'm not surprised by this). I'm not sure if they could be called duplicates so I will just edit the question to improve its readability.

Comment: @slugster Thanks for the response. As I noted in the previous comment, there are a lot of similar questions with accepted and upvoted answers so I will just improve the question's readability.